# jinja2 loop for indexed names

Tags: python, loops, jinja2

I have the following dictionaries list:

```
servers:
- name: web
  number: 3
- name: lb
  number: 2
```

I need the following output out of a jinja2 template:

```
web_1
web_2
web_3
lb_1
lb_2
```

I've tried looking into the jinja2 manual or some other examples here on stackoverflow but I found nothing useful for my use case.

```
{% for server in servers %}
{{ server.name }}_index
{% endfor %}
```

the code above doesn't work.

Comment: there is no code (just the jinja template). what 'does not work'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to add extra loop over the `number` field:

```
{% for server in servers %}
{%- for index in range(server.number) %}
{{- server.name }}_{{ index + 1 }}
{% endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

First loop iterates server entries, and the second one generates indexes within the specified range (`number` field).